# Gmail API - Is there a way to list messages in sorted order w.r.t. receive time?

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

Is there a way to list Gmail mails using Google Mail APIs in sorted order of receive time?

Although the API returns the mails in reverse chronological order. For a very small data set like 10 mails, I am finding a discrepancy.

Response of mail list API:

```
 {
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "15afb61b8d220a19",
   "threadId": "15afb61b8d220a19"
  },
  {
   "id": "15afb618f941d73f",
   "threadId": "15afb618f941d73f"
  },
  {
   "id": "15afb6174711c7af",
   "threadId": "15afb6174711c7af"
  },

  ...
  ...
  {
   "id": "159bc283f63d5eb7",
   "threadId": "159bc283f63d5eb7"
  },
  {
   "id": "159bc283dc97cd87",
   "threadId": "159bc283dc97cd87"
  },
  {
   "id": "159bc283d95f097c",
   "threadId": "159bc283d95f097c"
  }
 ],
 "resultSizeEstimate": 9
}
```

First message in response(**most recent**):

```
Id: 15afb61b8d220a19
Date: "Thu, 23 Mar 2017 19:06:08 +0530" 
internalDate: "1490276168000"
```

Second mail in list:

```
Id: 15afb618f941d73f
Date: "Thu, 23 Mar 2017 19:05:58 +0530"
internalDate: "1490276158000"
```

...
...
Second last mail in the list:

```
Id: 159bc283dc97cd87 
Date: "Fri, 20 Jan 2017 05:54:30 -0800" 
internalDate: "1484920470000"
```

Last mail in the list(**should be oldest, but is not**):

```
Id: 159bc283d95f097c
Date: "Fri, 20 Jan 2017 05:54:31 -0800"
internalDate: "1484920471000"
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's the expected behavior based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727961/in-what-order-does-threads-get-and-messages-get-return-a-list-of-items).

> ...`messages.list` does NOT return in date ASC or date DESC. They are returned randomly as far as I can tell.

You can also use the [search syntax](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) to filter by email's date.

Comment: If I use search syntax to filter messages between two dates, then are the returned messages sorted?

Comment: I tried using newer, after etc search syntax for the same set. But the results are in the same order i.e. not completely sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a parameter that should be offered but apparently not.  Still, it's pretty easy to sort results youself.

If you are using php you can use `usort()`.  First build an array of messages from your list with `internalDate` as a key (looks like you've done that).  If you wanted them in descending order:

```
usort($messages, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['internalDate'] <=> $a['internalDate'];
});
```